# How do I write this javascript regex for isogram detection In Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, regex

I found something using Javascript on another SO post, but I am wondering if there is a Python equivalent.

```
function isIsogram (str) {
    return !/(\w).*\1/i.test(str);
}
```

For my problem, I can allow spaces and hyphens, but no other repeating characters.
I thought it would be something like this, but obviously I'm way off.

```
def is_isogram(string: str):
    comp_re = re.compile(r'!/(\w).*\1/i')
    return comp_re.match(string)
```

Comment: `!` isn't part of the regexp, it's the `not` operator in JavaScript.

Comment: Regex isn't suitable for detecting isograms (except maybe of the first order).

Comment: Like `def isIsogram(s):
    return not re.search(r"(\w).*\1", s)` ?

Comment: Change `\w` to `[^- ]` if space and hyphen are the only characters that are allowed to repeat.

Comment: @Carcigenicate Your regex is strong enough, make that an answer.

Comment: Clarification request: is "Oslo" an isogram?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Python, perhaps this is an option.

Note that you don't need the case insensitive flag, as `\w` and the `.` match both upper and lowercase chars a-z

```
import re

def isIsogram(s):
    return not re.search(r"(\w).*\1", s)

strings = [
    "dialogue",
    "a",
    "testing",
    "abcdb"

]
for s in strings:
    print(f"{s} --> {isIsogram(s)}")
```

Output

```
dialogue --> True
a --> True
testing --> False
abcdb --> False
```

[Python demo](https://ideone.com/veMjcH)

---

To match any char except a whitspace char or hyphen, you can use a [negated character class](https://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html#negated):

```
([^-\s]).*\1
```

Comment: Talking of case: is "Oslo" an isogram?

Comment: Thank you so much! You and @Barmar were very helpful. Ultimately I've gone with the following: `def is_isogram(string: str):

    comp_re = re.compile(r'([^- ]).*\1', re.IGNORECASE)
    return not comp_re.search(string)`

Comment: @Joffan Honestly, I would not know what the rule for that is.

Comment: I get a couple test failures with your answer as it is because of case. Also, [^- ] allows hyphens and spaces.

Comment: @Moony That is ok, in that case you also don't need the `re.IGNORECASE` as the negated character class `[^- ]` matches upper and lower case chars a-z as well.

Comment: @Thefourthbird yeah, perhaps unfair to tag my question onto your answer... if "Oslo" isn't an isogram, I guess `return not re.search(r"(\w).*\1", s.lower())` in `isIsogram(s)` fixes it.

Comment: @Moony If you don't want to match either a hyphen or a whitespace character `([^-\s]).*\1` If you want to allow matching word characters, a space or hyphen `([\w -]).*\1`